# Undefined control sequence after compliling document in the part of tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

In the following snippet of code after compiling I get error message:

```
Undefined control sequence. ]{definition}{Defincja}{tbox_DEF_style}{}
```

and exactly the same error messages for proposition, lemma and theorem.
However I defined it

```
\NewTCBListing{verbbox}{ !O{} }{boxrule=1pt,sidebyside,skin=bicolor,colback=gray!10,colbacklower=white,valign=center,top=2pt,bottom=2pt,left=2pt,right=2pt,#1}
\makeatother
\definecolor{tcol_DEF}{HTML}{E40125} % Color for Definition
\definecolor{tcol_PRP}{HTML}{EB8407} % Color for Proposition
\definecolor{tcol_LEM}{HTML}{05C4D9} % Color for Lemma
\definecolor{tcol_THM}{HTML}{1346E4} % Color for Theorem
\definecolor{tcol_COR}{HTML}{7904C2} % Color for Corollary
\definecolor{tcol_REM}{HTML}{18B640} % Color for Remark
\definecolor{tcol_PRF}{HTML}{5A76B2} % Color for Proof
\definecolor{tcol_EXA}{HTML}{21340A} % Color for Example

\tcbset{
    tbox_DEF_style/.style={enhanced jigsaw,
        colback=tcol_DEF!10,colframe=tcol_DEF!80!black,,
        fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries,
        separator sign=.,label separator={},
        sharp corners,top=2pt,bottom=2pt,left=2pt,right=2pt,
        before skip=10pt,after skip=10pt,breakable
    },
    tbox_PRP_style/.style={enhanced jigsaw,
        colback=tcol_PRP!10,colframe=tcol_PRP!80!black,
        fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries,
        attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight},
        boxed title style={
            boxrule=0pt,boxsep=2.5pt,
            colback=tcol_PRP!80!black,colframe=tcol_PRP!80!black,
            sharp corners=uphill
        },
        separator sign=.,label separator={},
        top=\tcboxedtitleheight,bottom=2pt,left=2pt,right=2pt,
        before skip=10pt,after skip=10pt,drop fuzzy shadow,breakable
    },
    tbox_THM_style/.style={enhanced jigsaw,
        colback=tcol_THM!10,colframe=tcol_THM!80!black,
        fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries,coltitle=black,
        attach boxed title to top left={xshift=10pt,yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
        boxed title style={
            colback=tcol_THM!10,colframe=tcol_THM!80!black,height=16pt,bean arc
        },
        separator sign=.,label separator={},
        sharp corners,top=6pt,bottom=2pt,left=2pt,right=2pt,
        before skip=10pt,after skip=10pt,breakable
    },
    tbox_LEM_style/.style={enhanced jigsaw,
        colback=tcol_LEM!10,colframe=tcol_LEM!80!black,
        boxrule=0pt,
        fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries,
        attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight},
        boxed title style={
            boxrule=0pt,boxsep=2pt,
            colback=tcol_LEM!80!black,colframe=tcol_LEM!80!black,
            interior code={\fill[tcol_LEM!80!black] (interior.north west)--(interior.south west)--([xshift=-2mm]interior.south east)--([xshift=2mm]interior.north east)--cycle;
        }},
        separator sign=.,label separator={},
        frame hidden,borderline north={1pt}{0pt}{tcol_LEM!80!black},
        before upper={\hspace{\tcboxedtitlewidth}},
        sharp corners,top=2pt,bottom=2pt,left=5pt,right=5pt,
        before skip=10pt,after skip=10pt,breakable
    },
    tbox_COR_style/.style={enhanced jigsaw,
        colback=tcol_COR!10,colframe=tcol_COR!80!black,
        boxrule=0pt,
        fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries,coltitle=black,
        separator sign={},label separator={},
        description font=\normalfont\sffamily,
        description delimiters={(}{)},
        attach title to upper,after title={.\ },
        frame hidden,borderline west={2pt}{0pt}{tcol_COR},
        sharp corners,top=2pt,bottom=2pt,left=5pt,right=5pt,
        before skip=10pt,after skip=10pt,breakable
    },
}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section,
crefname={\color{tcol_DEF!50!black} definition}{\color{tcol_DEF!50!black} definitions},
Crefname={\color{tcol_DEF!50!black} Definition}{\color{tcol_DEF!50!black} Definitions}
]{definition}{Defincja}{tbox_DEF_style}{}
\newtcbtheorem[use counter from=definition,
crefname={\color{tcol_PRP!50!black} proposition}{\color{tcol_PRP!50!black} propositions},
Crefname={\color{tcol_PRP!50!black} Proposition}{\color{tcol_PRP!50!black} Propositions}
]{proposition}{Fakt}{tbox_PRP_style}{}
\newtcbtheorem[use counter from=definition,
crefname={\color{tcol_THM!50!black} theorem}{\color{tcol_THM!50!black} theorems},
Crefname={\color{tcol_THM!50!black} Theorem}{\color{tcol_THM!50!black} Theorems}
]{theorem}{Twierdzenie}{tbox_THM_style}{}
\newtcbtheorem[use counter from=definition,
crefname={\color{tcol_LEM!50!black} lemma}{\color{tcol_LEM!50!black} lemmas},
Crefname={\color{tcol_LEM!50!black} Lemma}{\color{tcol_LEM!50!black} Lemmas}
]{lemma}{Lemat}{tbox_LEM_style}{}
\newtcbtheorem[use counter from=definition,
crefname={\color{tcol_COR!50!black} corollary}{\color{tcol_COR!50!black} corollaries},
Crefname={\color{tcol_COR!50!black} Corollary}{\color{tcol_COR!50!black} Corollaries}
]{corollary}{Wniosek}{tbox_COR_style}{}
\makeatletter
```

Comment: Between \ExplSyntaxOn and \ExplSyntaxOff spaces are not recognized. It takes ~ . we must write separator~sign=.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, However I not used \ExplSyntaxOn and \ExplSyntaxOff.

Comment: do you load `\usepackage{cleveref}`?